# next jquery returns [] in chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I don't really understand why this:

```
$('.myitem').next('.exampleClass').css('display','none');
```

gives me

```
[]
```

(in chrome console) and

```
$(".myitem").parent().css('display','none');
```

does work and gives me the html code and actually does what i want it todo

Overall what does `[]` means in chome? `null`?

Basically i'm trying to find the parent `<li>` and hide it, then find the next `<li>` and show it.

Comment: Most likely you don't understand how .next() works. It only selects the very next element (the element that's index is the current element's index+1), and then only returns it if it matches the selector. it doesn't recursively look through all following elements looking for a match. `[]` is an empty array, and in this case means no elements were selected.

Comment: `[]` is an empty array. It means `.next()` didn't find anything matching. Does this really happen only in Chrome, or did you only try it in Chrome? Show your HTML and we can help you fix the code.

Comment: as Barmar stated `[]` means nothing was found. .next Looks for the immidiate next sibling. If you want the first sibling containing said class then use .nextAll like `$('.myitem').nextAll('.exampleClass').first().css('display','none');`. .nextAll goes through all next siblings, not just the first one and .first will stop it at the first one that matches

Comment: so how do i search for the next list item? I am doing closest to find the one I'm in...and don't really understand how do i find the next one to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[] is an empty array.  Many jQuery function ruturn an array of jQuery objects.  Your jQuery function didn't find anything that matched ".exampleClass" so it returned an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

It can return empty if the next sibling is not .exampleClass.

I'd use something like this:

```
$('.myitem').nextAll('.exampleClass').first().css('display','none');
```